# How can I made mandatory fields red on form load with model validations in mvc

Tags: jquery, css

I have used Model validations and remote attribute validation, All mandatory fields become red when submit button is click, Is is possible that all mandatory fields become red on form load?

Comment: you can use jquery for this purpose.

Comment: I don' think mvc wil do this for you you can place a red * against those feilds.

Comment: You might be using default mvc template which microsoft provides. They have designed the CSS style in site.css file which makes the validation messages to appear in red colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already have CSS to show the red border if input is invalid, just trigger the validation when the form load, but that will also show the validation message.

**css**

```
.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").valid();
});
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/slMStr)

Answer (score 0):

this helped me

```
input.input-validation-error,
textarea.input-validation-error,
select.input-validation-error
{
    background: #FEF1EC;
    border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
}
```